# How to emit an object with its value

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

I have an EventEmitter and i am emitting an object as below:

```
@Output() cellClick = new EventEmitter();
private _cellClicked(data: any){
      let emitData: any = {
        colId: data.column.colId,
        rowId: data.node.id,
        item: {}
      };
      if (emitWithdata){
          this.cellClick.next(emitData); // Here  i need to send my data also, and it need to append to the value Data.item=data not just the Data object.
      } 
      if (emitWithNodata){
              this.cellClick.next(emitData); // here i just pass the emitData with empty item, which is correct
      }


}
```

How to pass the data with the emitData? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot understand this question. Whatever you want to emit, just emit it  What do you mean by "my data"? *How to emit an object with its value*
 An object **IS** its value. (BTW, don't you want to use `emit` instead of `next`?).

Comment: sorry my data means, the `data` passed in the parameter of the function

Comment: So if I emit `emitData` in my listener i waill have the object, correct but the `item` will be empty. I need to pass the `data` which is the parameter of `_cellClicked` function to be passed to my parent or listener also

Comment: Then just replace `item: {}` with `item: data`?

Comment: Yeah, but during declaration, the item will be empty = `item:{}` but in my condition check `if (emitWithdata)` I need to append the data in.

Comment: Because not always i need to send my data to my listener

Answer (score 7):

If we follow Angular EventEmitter API:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html

1. change the EventEmiter declaration to use : EventEmitter
2. To send the data you have to use the emmit method.

Your code should be like this:

```
@Output() cellClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
private _cellClicked(data: any){
      let emitData: any = {
        colId: data.column.colId,
        rowId: data.node.id,
        item:{}
      };
      if (emitWithdata){
          emitData.item=data;
          this.cellClick.emit(emitData); // Here  i need to send my data also, and it need to append to the value Data.item=data not just the Data object.
      } 
}
```

Comment: the item is an empty object in declaration. The data will appended inside the emitwithdata condetion

Answer (score 6):

To send data back to event handler, you can write like this:

```
this.cellClick.emit({data : emitData, orderData: someData});
```

Comment: I dun want to pass two separate long, Any way I can send only emitData, but item will be the data

Answer (score 6):

This is how you do it as of Angular 11. I'm sure older versions are somewhat similar. Also, you can learn more details by reading the [documentation on Event Binding](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding).

You can definitely use an `any` object declared on the fly, however this example will show how to do it using a strongly typed object.

A strongly typed object, declared somewhere in your application:

```
export interface MyCustomObject {
    rowId: number;
    columnId: number;
    item: any;
}
```

Child markup:

```
<div (click)="onCellClicked()"></div>
```

Child component's TS file:

```
import { MyCustomObject } from './some-file.models';

@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.less']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    //whatever name you assign this Output variable,
    //is the event name you'll bind to on the parent markup
    @Output() cellClicked = new EventEmitter<MyCustomObject>();
    
    constructor() { }
    
    public onCellClicked(): void {
        const obj: MyCustomObject = {
            rowId: 5;
            columnId: 24;
            item: {
                foo: 'abc'
            };
        }
        
        this.cellClicked.emit(obj);
    }
}
```

Parent markup file which makes use of Child component:

```
<!-- $event param will hold the passed value -->
<!-- also notice the use of (cellClicked) as defined by the childs Output variable -->
<child-component (cellClicked)="onChildCellClicked($event)"></child-component>
```

Parent TS file:

```
import { MyCustomObject } from './some-file.models';

@Component({
    selector: 'parent-component',
    templateUrl: './parent-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./parent-component.component.less']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }
    
    public onChildCellClicked(event: MyCustomObject): void {
        //do something on the parent with the data
        console.log('parent cell click event: ', event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- In child comp:

```
model: Model;
@Output() modelChange = new EventEmitter<Model>(); 
this.modelChange.emit(this.model);
```

2- In parent component:
in the template:

```
<app-child-model (modelChange)="getInfoModel($event)"></app-child-model>
```

in comp.ts

```
getInfoModel(event: Model){
console.log("New event", event);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Output() cellClick = new EventEmitter();
private _cellClicked(data: any){
      let emitData: any = {
        colId: data.column.colId,
        rowId: data.node.id,
        item: {}
      };
      if (emitWithdata){
          this.cellClick.next(emitData); // Here  i need to send my data also, and it need to append to the value Data.item=data not just the Data object.
      } 
      if (emitWithNodata){
              this.cellClick.next({...emitData, ...{item:{value:'temp'}}); // here i just pass the emitData with empty item, which is correct
      }


}
```

item property will be overwritten and will be send in event emtiter params